# UIView won't animate after Tabbar selects UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UIViewController VC1 that contains a UIImageView loadingImg. When you segue from a previous UIViewController VC0, it animates. Here is some code from VC1:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    animate()
}

func animate() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
        self.loadingImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

I also have a tabbar, where VC0 is one of the root view controllers. Once VC0 has segued to VC1, when you click on to another root view controller and then back, loadingImg is no longer animating. How can I keep loadingImg animating even if I'm using tabbar to switch to different view controllers and back?

Comment: Tried both of these things, neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set original position of UIView when you switch UIViewController in ViewDidAppear like below

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.loadingImg.transform = .identity
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

[image]